# Would a "Quiet Check Valve" help when check valve is only on backup sump pump pipe?

Tags: plumbing, valve

Whenever it rains our sump pump sounds like a jack hammer when it shuts off. I had always assumed it was just the sump pump itself that was noisy, but as I did some searching this morning I came across a mention of replacing a regular check valve with a "Quiet Check Valve", and watched a couple videos where the pump initially sounded like mine, but after replacing with the quiet check valve the hammering noise was gone. I was about to order one, when I realized my configuration was different, and I'm not really sure how my configuration works or if the new valve would help.

My understanding of the image below is that "A" is the pipe from the primary sump pump. "B" is a Zoeller Water Powered Emergency Backup Sump Pump. The check valve "C" is above the emergency sump pump, so I think that check valve would always be closed.

My questions are:

1) If I replaced the check valve "C" with a new "quiet check valve", would that make any difference to quiet the hammering when the primary pump shuts off?

2) When the primary pump shuts off, does the water above run straight down the y connector (part "D" in the picture) to stop at the check valve "C"?

3) If so, would that water fill up above the check valve "C", and then run down the y connector "D" to go down the primary sump pump's pipe "A", and back into the pit?

4) Does the connector "E" serve any special purpose?

5) Would adding a quiet check valve in the primary pump's pipe "A" be of any value?

Thank you for any insight!

[image: Sump pump pipes]

Comment: To tell the truth only 1 check valve is needed with most sump pumps as they already have one, but I am leaving this as a comment as I have never heard your problem even with multiple pumps. And only 1 check valve just above the y that connected them , worked great but I was only there for 2 + years after that. To me each pump should have a foot or check then 2 more above , my guess they are probably filled with sludge. 1 valve good, 2 maybe ok 3+ just a lot of restrictions to catch silt and other debris.